# How to properly use the StateT monad here?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

I'm have to make a very small game in Haskell for a course I follow. So I created the play-function, but now I have trouble changing it's type signature.

```
play :: [[String]] -> StateT GameState IO Score
play input = 
do 
    liftIO $ clearScreen
    (answered, correct) <- get
    if True
    then
        do
            liftIO $ putStrLn "Well done! Your answer was correct!"
            liftIO $ putStrLn ("So far, you answered " ++ (show answered) ++ " questions")
            put (answered + 1, correct + 1)
            liftIO $
                do
                    temp <- getLine
                    putStrLn temp
    else
        do
            liftIO $ putStrLn "I'm sorry, you're wrong..."
            put (answered + 1, correct)
    play input
```

Now, please don't mind the if True statement, that's just for testing. Now this function works, but I have to make it work with another type signature to. The type signature of the function play should be:

```
play :: IO (Either ParseError [[String]]) -> StateT GameState IO Score
```

But I have absolutely no idea on how to use my `StateT` monad then? How can I do this? The IO `(Either ParseError [[String]])` monad is a result of the parseFromFile-function from the missingH-package.

Comment: I don't see why you need to alter `play`. Whatever calls `parseFromFile` should be deciding, based on that result, whether or not to call `play`.

Comment: @chepner Ok, but how can I call play with the `[[String]]` instead of the `IO (Either ParseError [[String]])`? I don't have access to the `[[String]]` rightaway.

Comment: You can use `lift :: IO (Either ParseError [[String]]) -> StateT GameState IO (Either ...)` and then use monadic bind (`>>=` or inside a `do` block) on this value. You will still need to deal with the `ParseError` - perhaps throwing an exception or changing your monad to `StateT GameState (ErrorT SomeErrorType IO)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The caller should be handling that.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  parsed <- parseFromFileStuff
  case parsed of
    Left parseerror -> handleErrorStuff
    Right input -> evalStateT (play input) initialState
```

By the way, you never actually return a score, so the return type of `play` should be `Void`, not `Score`. Also you should tighten that recursion by removing `play`s last line, changing its return type to `()`, and replacing `play input` by `forever (play input)`. Oh and you never use the input.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works as expected :) The input is used in another function that I didn't include in this implementation of play ;)